# save multiple selected datagrid rows to EF table

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

My WPF form has DataGrid. The first column is a CheckBox column. I would like when the button is clicked, all the CheckBoxes row is checked, insert into a EF table. How to do it? I will appreciate for sample.
Thanks.

Comment: Where's your existing code? What have you tried already?

Comment: I found such code.
 <code>
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        List ChkedRow = new List();
    
        for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++) 
        {
             if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["chkcol"].Value) == true) 
             {
                ChkedRow.Add(i);
             }
         }

         if (ChkedRow.Count == 0) 
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Select atleast one checkbox");
             return;
         }
     }</code>

But it does not work in WPF

Comment: Please edit the question and add your comment as well formatted code to the question. This will help us and future readers

Answer (score 0):

> I would like when the button is clicked, all the CheckBoxes row is checked, insert into a EF table

This is a bit cryptic. Do you want that all rows that have a Checked value in the column with the CheckBox are added / updated / deleted to your database using Entity Framework?

Anyway, whatever you want to do, you should [separate your concerns.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). In this case, you should make methods to read what is in your DataGrid, and methods that can Insert / Update / delete elements that are in a sequence to your database.

Alas you didn't tell us a lot about what is in your DataGridView, nor what is in your DbContext.

As you are using WPF, you should use the MVVM pattern: You should have a View, a Model and a ViewModel.

The View is the interface with the operator. The View contains the Grid that shows the current value and that the operator uses to make changes. The View also contains the button that the operator presses to notify that the changes should be processed.

The Model contains the actual data. The `ViewModel` is between that View and the Model: it knows what part of the data should be displayed, it knows actions should be done on the data, but it doesn't know how the data is displayed, nor how the actions are started.

So the ViewModel knows that it should provide a command to process the changes, but it doesn't know whether this is started via a small round blue button, or a large triangular one, or maybe the command is started using a menu item. These visual parts are not part of the ViewModel.

If you have no idea what I'm talking about, then I suggest that you'd spent an afternoon reading about MVVM, WPF properties and Commands.

### ViewModel

After the operator edits the contents of the datagrid he presses a button to notify that the changes should be processed. Your code should be something like:

```
class CustomerViewModel
{
    public ObservableColection<DisplayedCustomer> DisplayedCustomers
    {
        get => ...
    }

    public ICommand CommandProcessChanges {get; } ...

    private bool CanProcessChanges(...)
    {
        ...
    }

    private void ProcessChanges(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

When method `ProcessChanges` is called, you know that the operator has finished making his changes, and that all changes are in Property `Customers`.

It is your task, to update the changes in the Model. The ViewModel does not know, and does not care whether the Model saves the data in a database, or in a CSV-file, or maybe the data is transferred over the internet. All that the ViewModel knows, is that the operator wants some data to be processed.

Your ViewModel you know nothing about CheckBoxes. Your ViewModel doesn't know how the DisplayedCustomers are displayed. All it knows, is that the contents of the GridView are in DisplayedCustomers.

I don't know what your CheckBoxes mean: do you want to remove all Customers where the CheckBox is checked? Do you want to fetch their data? Anyway, your DisplayedCustomer will be something like:

```
class DisplayedCustomer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Customer properties:
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ...

    // properties for the CheckBox columns:
    public bool IsDeleteRequested {get; set;}
    public bool IsFetchRequested {get; set;}
}
```

For simplicity I omitted the code to NotifyPropertyChanged.

The latter two properties are used to display check boxes. If the operator checks / unchecks them, the Boolean values will be automatically updated.

```
private void ProcessChanges(...)
{
    var customerIdsToFetch = this.DisplayedCustomers
        .Where(customer => customer.IsFetchRequested())
        .Select(customer => customer.Id);
    var fetchedCustomers = this.FetchCustomers(customerIdsToFetch);
    this.ProcessFetchedCustomers(fetchedCustomers);

    var customersToDelete = this.DisplayedCustomers
        .Where(customer => customer.IsDeleteRequested);
    this.Model.DeleteCustomers(customersToDelete);
}
```

Did you notice, that in the ViewModel, you don't know anything about CheckBoxes?

```
IEnumerable<Customer> FetchCustomers(IEnumerable<int> customerIds)
{
    return this.CustomerModel.FetchCustomers(customerIds);
}

void ProcessFetchedCustomers(IEnumerable<Customer> fetchedCustomers)
{
    // TODO: what do you want to do with the fetchedCustomers,
    // if your View needs them, for instance to display their names in a ListBox:
    this.FetchedCustomerNames = fetchedCustomers
        .Select(customer => customer.Name)
        .ToList();
}
```

Note: your ViewModel doesn't know what the View does with these fetched customer names. So if you decide you change the visual representation, for instance you don't want to show them in a red ListBox, but in a LightBlue ComboBox, your ViewModel doesn't have to change

### The Model

So you have separated your concerns into: a visual representation (View), the data that must be visuaized (ViewModel) and the source of your data (Model).

Only the Model knows that the data is stored in a database. If you decide to save the data in XML format, or CSV-file, neither your View, nor your ViewModel has to change.

```
class CustomerModel
{
    public ICollection<Customer> FetchCustomersById(IEnumerable<int> customerIds)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new OrderContext())
        {
            return dbContext.Customers
                .Where(customer => customerIds.Contains(customer.Id))
                .ToList();
        }
    }

    public void DeleteCustomers(IEnumerable<int> customerIdsToDelete)
    {
         using (var dbContext = ...)
         {
             var customersToDelete = dbContext.Customers
                .Where(customer => customerIdsToDelete.Contains(customer.Id))
                .ToList();
             dbContext.Customers.DeleteRange(customersToDelete);
             dbContext.SaveChanges();
         }
    }
}
```

Suppose in a future version, you want to be able to un-delete customers. So a Delete doesn't remove it from the database, it only sets a boolean property IsObsolete

```
public ICollection<Customer> FetchCustomersById(IEnumerable<int> customerIds)
{
    using (var dbContext = new OrderContext())
    {
        return dbContext.Customers
            .Where(customer => customerIds.Contains(customer.Id)
                            && customer => !customer.IsObsolete)
            .ToList();
        }
    }

    public void DeleteCustomers(IEnumerable<int> customerIdsToDelete)
    {
         using (var dbContext = ...)
         {
             foreach (int id in customerIdsToDelete)
             {
                 var customerToDelete = dbContext.Customers.Find(id);
                 customerToDelete.IsObsolete = true;
                 dbContext.SaveChanges();
             }
         }
    }
```

So if an Administrator wants to Undelete a Customer who was deleted by accident, all he has to do is set property IsObsolete to false.

Now, although you have changed your internal Customer, neither your View, nor your ViewModel will notice this. You can enforce this flexibility more by using interfaces.

### Conclusion

You separated your concerns: you created a separate View / ViewModel / Model. Hence all your View has to do is make sure that the DisplayedCustomer is updated. All your ViewModel has to do is process the DisplayedCustomers, all your Model has to do is update the database.

Only the parts that know anything about CheckBoxes have to worry about checkboxes. The part that knows about databases, doesn't know anything about checkboxes.